# can't select by time in C# Windows FormApp

Tags: c#, select, webforms

I'm having problem with my C# Windows Form Application
I need to select data by time period
Here's my code:

```
string queryAll = "SELECT * FROM EX_SUM WHERE YEAR 
BETWEEN '"+ from + "' AND '" + to + "'";
```

I have textboxes from and to
But it not working.
But when i'm write this code:

```
string queryAll = "SELECT * FROM EX_SUM WHERE YEAR BETWEEN '05.05.2010' and '05.05.2015' ";
```

it works correctly

Comment: please post the content of `from` and `to`. Preferably directly from the Debugger

Comment: if you want data by `year` then only pass year in query. dont pass full date

Comment: @Mong Zhu String from = textBox1.Text;
String to = textBox2.Text;

Comment: @ershoaib I need full information, by year, month and days

Comment: so `YEAR` is your column name but store full date,  right?

Comment: I was talking about the actual values of these variables. "Preferably directly from the Debugger". You can also post a screenshot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: `But it not working.` What specifically isn't working?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a multi line string, you need to add `"` in the end.

```
string queryAll = "SELECT * FROM EX_SUM WHERE YEAR " +

"BETWEEN '"+ from + "' AND '" + to + "'";
```